# Regular expression to validate string format <whole-number>@<whole-number>

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to create a regular expression for a string in the format

```
<whole-number>@<whole-numbers>%
for example:
1@100%,
9@50%,
5@10%,
```

- only single numeric digit should be allowed before @
- only @ special character after the numeric digit
- there should be only 3 or less numeric digits after the @
- only % special character should be allowed at the end of the string.

the following examples are not valid.

```
0@100%,
a@50%,
1@abc%,
```

I have created a regular expression but it is not working as expected

```
([0-9]{1}[@]{1}[0-9]{0,3})
```

Comment: Why would you write a meaningless `{1}`? Why would you put `@` inside square brackets? Do you really want to allow NO digits after the `@`? Why are you not using `\d`? Perhaps a review of the regexp documentation is in order. Why did you leave off the `%` from the end of your regexp? When you say "not working as expected, you need to tell us HOW it is not working.

Comment: Why is `0@100%` an invalid case?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
/^\d@\d+%$/
```

`\d` is for digits. `+` says one or more characters

The way you have written your regex, it seems you only need 3 numbers after `@`, if you want that then the way in which you have written it, it should be something like:

```
/^[0-9]{1}@[0-9]{0,3}%$/
```

You were missing the `%` character match and the anchor tags.

Or else you could just use:

```
/^\d@\d{0,3}%$/
```

Comment: yes after @ I need only 3 or less digits
but in the regular expression I have written I am not sure about the @
like I have to accept only @ after adding the first digit was typed between 0-9 @Ashish Ranjan

Comment: I don't follow? so is even a single digit valid?? for example? `1`. The modified regex of your regex version will match everything like: `onedigit@uptoThreeDigits%`

Comment: @gary: also, please see the updated answer, I had missed the anchor tags.

Comment: Why is `/g` necessary here?

Comment: Oh no, it is not, I was testing it under: https://regexr.com/, I will update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @ashish Ranjan

Answer (score 2):

You want the string to start with a one digit number from 1 to 9 (not 0), followed by `@`, then by a number with at most 3 digits and ending with `%`.

Then use:

```
/^[1-9]@\d{1,3}%$/
```

```js
console.log('4@55%',/^[1-9]@\d{1,3}%$/.test('4@55%'))
console.log('2@678%',/^[1-9]@\d{1,3}%$/.test('2@678%'))
console.log('22@22%',/^[1-9]@\d{1,3}%$/.test('22@22%'))
console.log('a@11%',/^[1-9]@\d{1,3}%$/.test('a@11%'))
console.log('0@99%',/^[1-9]@\d{1,3}%$/.test('0@99%'))
console.log('3@%',/^[1-9]@\d{1,3}%$/.test('3@%'))
console.log('1@abc%',/^[1-9]@\d{1,3}%$/.test('1@abc%'))
```